# cannot update value from dropdownbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to update records using C# ASP.NET. I have the following tables and textboxes.. The process would be to search for the EmployeeID first. Input the `EmployeeID` on txtID and hit  `btnSearch`. The textboxes will be populated then by the values of `EmployeeID = txtID.Text`. `txtLname`, `txtFname`, etc will be populated. To save the changes, hit `btnUpdate`.

But whenever I try to click on the dropdownbox to change the department of the employee, there's no error but the change wasn't saved. Also, when I try to change the EmployeeID, it returns this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on this line `dRow["EmployeeID"] = txtID.Text;`.

EmployeeID and DeptID are both set as Primary Key

---

[image]   [image]

Here's my code for btnSearch_Click()

```
        DataRow myRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Find(int.Parse(txtID.Text));

        txtID.Text = myRow["EmployeeID"].ToString();
        txtLname.Text = myRow["Lname"].ToString();
        txtFname.Text = myRow["Fname"].ToString();
        txtMname.Text = myRow["Mname"].ToString();
        txtAddress.Text = myRow["Address"].ToString();
        txtEmail.Text = myRow["Email"].ToString();
        txtPhone.Text = myRow["Phone"].ToString();
        txtJobtitle.Text = myRow["Jobtitle"].ToString();
        txtSalary.Text = myRow["Salary"].ToString();
        drpDepartments.SelectedValue = myRow["DeptID"].ToString();`
```

Here's my code for btnUpdate_click()

```
        cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(daEmp);

        DataRow dRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Find(int.Parse(txtID.Text));
        dRow["EmployeeID"] = txtID.Text;
        dRow["DeptID"] = drpDepartments.SelectedValue;
        dRow["Lname"] = txtLname.Text;
        dRow["Fname"] = txtFname.Text;
        dRow["Mname"] = txtMname.Text;
        dRow["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
        dRow["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
        dRow["Phone"] = txtPhone.Text;
        dRow["Jobtitle"] = txtJobtitle.Text;
        dRow["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;

        daEmp.Update(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].AcceptChanges();
```

Here's the code for Page_Load

```
            sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr);
        daEmp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", sConn);
        daDep = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblDepartment", sConn);
        dsEmp = new DataSet();
        dsDep = new DataSet();

        daEmp.Fill(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        daDep.Fill(dsDep, "tblDepartment");

        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Columns["EmployeeID"] };

        drpDepartments.DataSource = dsDep.Tables["tblDepartment"];
        drpDepartments.DataTextField = "Description";
        drpDepartments.DataValueField = "DeptID";
        drpDepartments.DataBind();
```

I just don't understand why this is happening. Please help me, I'm new to ASP.NET. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code for your `Page_Load` event.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I added the `Page_Load`

Comment: Do you know how to debug your code in Visual Studio?

Comment: Upward for the good way of asking question.

Answer (score 1):

This line here is the problem:

```
DataRow dRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Find(int.Parse(txtID.Text));
```

The issue is that the `Text` property of the text box named `txtID` is empty, thus the parsing of an empty string does not find a row in the database and `dRow` is `null`. So the first attempt to use `dRow` is on this line:

```
dRow["EmployeeID"] = txtID.Text;
```

And kaboom!

My recommendation is to put a guard clause in before you even try to find the row in the database, like this:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtId.Text))
{
    // Yes, the text box has a value so try to look it up
    DataRow dRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Find(int.Parse(txtID.Text));

    // Is dRow null?
    if(dRow != null)
    {
        dRow["EmployeeID"] = txtID.Text;
        dRow["DeptID"] = drpDepartments.SelectedValue;
        dRow["Lname"] = txtLname.Text;
        dRow["Fname"] = txtFname.Text;
        dRow["Mname"] = txtMname.Text;
        dRow["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
        dRow["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
        dRow["Phone"] = txtPhone.Text;
        dRow["Jobtitle"] = txtJobtitle.Text;
        dRow["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;
    }
}
else
{
    // Unable to find an empty string value in the database so don't even try
    // You can display an error message maybe or throw an exception, etc.
}
```

UPDATE:

Your departments drop down is not updating, because on every page load (initial page load or post back), the code is re-binding the drop down before the code to save it to the database has run. In ASP.NET WebForms, the `Page_Load` happens before the  click event handler (`btnUpdate_click()` in this case), so you are wiping out the choice made by the user and then trying to do the save.

In your `Page_Load`, try this instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Do not do these things on every post back to the server
        sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr);
        daEmp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", sConn);
        daDep = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblDepartment", sConn);
        dsEmp = new DataSet();
        dsDep = new DataSet();

        daEmp.Fill(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        daDep.Fill(dsDep, "tblDepartment");

        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Columns["EmployeeID"] };

        drpDepartments.DataSource = dsDep.Tables["tblDepartment"];
        drpDepartments.DataTextField = "Description";
        drpDepartments.DataValueField = "DeptID";
        drpDepartments.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe I should just disable the txtID so the value cannot be changed, since EmployeeID is Primary Key. How about for the drop down box? It's not updating.

Comment: If I change `dRow["DeptID"] = drpDepartments.SelectedValue;` to `dRow["DeptID"] = drpDepartments.DataValueField;` I'm getting this error `Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <DeptID> in DeptID Column.  Expected type is Int32.`

Comment: @user2971155 - see updated answer to put conditional logic in the `Page_Load` event.

Comment: @user2971155 - you want to keep using `drpDepartments.SelectedValue`, but read my updated answer to explain why `SelectedValue` is getting trashed from your code re-binding the drop down every post back to the server.

Comment: I tried it but still getting this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when I search for the EmployeeID. This line `DataRow myRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Find(int.Parse(txtID.Text));`

Comment: Should I use `SelectedValue` or `DataValueField?`

Comment: @user2971155 - `SelectedValue`, because `DataValueField` refers to the database field to populate the values in the drop down list, while `SelectedValue` is the particular value selected by the user.